# Mapping that fixes a point after a rotation

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

What is the mapping that rotates the entire complex plane through an angle $\theta$ about a given point $z_{0}$.

**My approach** : The mapping $w_{1}=e^{i \theta} z $
rotates the plane through the angle $\theta$ about the origin. In particular, the point $z_{0}$ is mapped to the point $e^{i \theta} z_{0}$.

I'm stuck here on how to establish the mapping to the given question. Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: Translate $z_0$ to the origin, then rotate, then move it back?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $z \mapsto z - z_0$ translates the complex plane so that the point $z_0$ moves to the origin.

Consider applying this translation, then a rotation, then an inverse translation to move everything back in place.